# fixing ESPNConversations (add pause button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

Its their new discussion board. (http://espn.go.com/nba/conversation?id=310605006)  The problem is, the real time updates keep adding new comments so it keeps scrolling away from whatever you're reading, for example right after a game when thousands of people are adding comments.  Its really ridiculous.  So just trying to write a greasemonkey script where you can hit a button and it will pause the board updates.

The pause function is what I don't know - what is the most basic straightforward way to do that - something that temporarily disables ajax or the like I'm thinking, but anything that works.  (Don't know for sure its ajax they're using.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no set way to pause AJAX.  It all depends on the page details.

In this case, that page pauses updates when you mouse over the conversation area.  And that page uses jQuery and the *Echo Stream* library.

So you could have your script create a button that sends `mouseover` <sup>1</sup> events (toggling to send `mouseout` to clear).

To pause the comments from the Firebug console:

```
jQuery ('div.echo-stream-body').mouseover ();
```

To pause the comments from a Greasemonkey script:

```
unsafeWindow.jQuery ('div.echo-stream-body').mouseover ();
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

For help writing a script from scratch for that page, try the [userscripts.org forum](http://userscripts.org/forums/2).

For specific code problems, we can help here (in another question).

---

<sup>1</sup> Or you could probably find the function that echo stream fires on hover events and hook in directly.

Comment: Thanks, just now seeing this - was confused about your comment that it pauses when mousing over the conversation area; don't recall that - have to check it out and see if I can get the rest of this to work...

Comment: I just realized something - that Pause feature on MouseRollover is something they've added in the past 24 hours or so - You must have gone there maybe an hour or something after it went on line.  This wasn't there previously.  Since it pauses on rollover now, that's all that's necessary. I know its new - everyone was complaining about this previously.

Comment: Well, good timing then.  It's also good to know that that site is responsive to UI problems and complaints.