# fixing ESPNConversations (add pause checkbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

[ESPNConversations](http://scores.espn.go.com/nba/conversation?gameId=310609006)

Trying to add a checkbox that pauses/resumes live comments.  (The way it works now it pauses/resumes when the mouse is rolled over to the client area or rolled out).  I'm following the direction of Brock Adams [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237066/fixing-espnconversations-add-pause-button) but its not working (The checkbox below is OK, just the actual pause/resume functionality is not working - at all.)

```
function paused() {
  return false;
}

function pause_click() {

   if (this.checked) {
     $("div.echo-stream-body").bind("mouseout",paused);   
     $("div.echo-stream-body").mouseover();     
   }
   else   {
     $("div.echo-stream-body").unbind("mouseout",paused);   
     $("div.echo-stream-body").mouseout();
   }
}

function add_pause_checkbox() {

  $(".echo_sort_down").after("<span style='position:relative;  top:-3px; margin-left:540px;'><input  type='checkbox' name='pause_gm' id='pause_gm' value='Pause' onClick='pause_click()' /><span style='position:relative; top:-2px;'>Pause</span></span>");

  $("#pause_gm").click(pause_click);
}

$(document).ready(add_pause_checkbox);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. You need to use the page's copy of jQuery in this case.  So all instances of `$` need to be `unsafeWindow.jQuery`.
2. Do not key off structures that will be loaded by JS after the GM script fires!  For example, `.echo_sort_down` will often not exist yet.

   In this case, insert before `#echostream1`.
3. Avoid inline styles.  Code will be clearer and easier to fiddle with.  Use CSS via `GM_addStyle()`.

The following works, with the exception discussed below...

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _ESPN pause foo.
// @include         http://scores.espn.go.com/nba/*
// ==/UserScript==

function paused (zEvent) {
    return false;
}

function pause_click () {

    if (this.checked) {
        unsafeWindow.jQuery ("div.echo-stream-body").bind ("mouseout", paused);
        unsafeWindow.jQuery ("div.echo-stream-body").mouseover ();
    }
    else {
        unsafeWindow.jQuery ("div.echo-stream-body").unbind ("mouseout", paused);
        unsafeWindow.jQuery ("div.echo-stream-body").mouseout ();
    }
}

unsafeWindow.jQuery ("#echostream1").before (
    "<span class='mySpan'><input type='checkbox' id='pause_gm'/><span>Pause</span></span>"
);
unsafeWindow.jQuery ("#pause_gm").click (pause_click);


GM_addStyle ( (<><![CDATA[
    span.mySpan
    {
        position:       relative;
        top:            -3px;
        margin-left:    540px;
    }
    span.mySpan span
    {
        position:       relative;
        top:            -2px;
    }
]]></>).toString () );
```

### Important:

Note that binding `mouseout` has no effect.  That is, the checkbox will work to pause the conversation, but if the user then mouses over and then back out, the conversation will resume and the checkbox will be out of sync.

This is most likely because we can't guarantee that our bound function fires before the page's.

Some possible workarounds to explore:

1. Find the function that the page's mouseout hooks into and then unbind and rebind the page's mouseout when the checkbox is clicked.
2. Throw a transparent overlay over the conversation area and use it to intercept mouseout events as necessary.
3. Event-listener binding order is no-doubt covered in other SO questions.  Search for how others might have handled a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Brock Adams -

Thanks! Responding to you here so I can provide some code.

It seems not using unsafewindow is what was the crux of the problem, but also I found I had to use echo-item-content instead of echo-stream-body.  (see code below). Don't know why I can't refer to echo_sort_down instead of echostream1 as if the latter exists, then so will the former.  And also I was executing it only on $(document).ready (which I notice you removed).  But there is a formatting problem if just using echostream1.before.  If I could access echo-stream-state (child of echostream1)  then I could do echo-stream-state.before,  but had problems accessing it.

But anyway, the code below I've gotten to work for now, will consider what you've done with GM_addStyle.

Thanks again.

```
function paused (zEvent) {
    return false;
}

function pause_click () {

    if (this.checked) {
        unsafeWindow.jQuery ("div.echo-item-content").bind ("mouseout", paused);
        unsafeWindow.jQuery ("div.echo-item-content:first").mouseover ();
    }
    else {
        unsafeWindow.jQuery ("div.echo-item-content").unbind ("mouseout", paused);
        unsafeWindow.jQuery ("div.echo-item-content:first").mouseout ();
    }
}

function add_pause_checkbox() {

  unsafeWindow.jQuery (".echo_sort_down").after("<span style='position:relative;  top:-3px; margin-left:500px;'><input  type='checkbox' name='pause_gm' id='pause_gm' value='Pause' onClick='pause_click()' /><span style='position:relative; top:-2px;'>Pause</span></span>");

  unsafeWindow.jQuery ("#pause_gm").click(pause_click);
}

unsafeWindow.jQuery (document).ready(add_pause_checkbox);
```

Comment: +1 for posting code you ended with.  Note that `(document).ready()` is not really needed because GM will only fire at the same event anyway (unless the page defers the jQuery load (it doesn't)).